# Paypal dropping options when redirected to mobile checkout

Tags: paypal

I have a site with an express checkout integration that works as intended on a desktop site. Our problem is if the user is on mobile, either a tablet or phone. Paypal redirects the user to the mobile version of checkout as intended (through nothing we've implemented, just paypal's own browser detection), however all our product options (os0, os1, os2, etc) get dropped from the order. This only happens on mobile. Any ideas? At this point, I'd be willing to settle for preventing paypal from redirecting to mobile checkout if there's a way to do that. I just need my product options to get passed.

EDIT

Note personal information has been changed to xxxxx

**IPN of working desktop checkout:**
*mc_gross=5.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_id=NYFC4NGFCRW42&tax=0.00&payment_date=20:02:11 Jan 10, 2015 PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&first_name=xxxxx&option_selection1=xxxxx&option_selection2=xxxxx&option_selection3=&option_selection4=&mc_fee=0.41&option_selection5=xxxxx&option_selection6=&option_selection7=&notify_version=3.8&option_selection8=xxxxx&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=xxxxx&quantity=0&verify_sign=ABXSYHEzCy4BoIX1KIl0txa8uYmBA7VgPsD2tzo1lLjCWx8GqFjgW6JO&payer_email=xxxxx&option_name1=Name&option_name2=Address&option_name3=Email&option_name4=Phone&option_name5=Donation Name&option_name6=Level&option_name7=Comments&option_name8=Referral&txn_id=5H921436HB101013Y&payment_type=instant&last_name=xxxxx&receiver_email=xxxxx&payment_fee=0.41&receiver_id=DFED6RGTUV25C&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Donation: Dedicated Ice Fund&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=5.00&ipn_track_id=ddc01e911e096*

**IPN of mobile checkout with exact same product/options:**
*mc_gross=5.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=NYFC4NGFCRW42&tax=0.00&address_street=xxxxx&payment_date=19:28:24 Jan 10, 2015 PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=946014341&first_name=xxxxx&mc_fee=0.41&address_country_code=US&address_name= &notify_version=3.8&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=xxxxx&address_country=United States&address_city=xxxxx&quantity=0&verify_sign=AIg7G10R6skhA5mGdmcaVrtIURzYAMpUHL6KwbBx3ftMmrQCTJwUtszP&payer_email=xxxxx&txn_id=3XJ61963J58333610&payment_type=instant&last_name=xxxxx&address_state=CA&receiver_email=xxxxx&payment_fee=0.41&receiver_id=DFED6RGTUV25C&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Donation: Dedicated Ice Fund&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&transaction_subject=Donation: Dedicated Ice Fund&payment_gross=5.00&ipn_track_id=1caea13fd3be4*

Checkout screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKun2.jpg

Comment: Can you provide samples of the API requests when it does and doesn't work?  Screenshots would be helpful, too.  I don't believe I've ever run into this issue.  Maybe the options aren't showing up on the review page in PayPal mobile, but are they still included on the final transaction details?  They should be as long as they're getting passed in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Edited to include IPN messages and screenshots. It's not just the review page, they don't show up in the transaction details either.

Comment: Those screenshots look like Payments Standard, but you had mentioned PayPal Express.  Which are you using for sure?  I was asking to see the API request, assuming that's what you're using, as opposed to the IPN data.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing, though, that you'll need to bring to PayPal's attention.  The best way to do that is through their [MTS System](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  Create a ticket there and include all the API, IPN, and screenshot details you can provide.

Comment: you're right - it's standard. other who have looked into it seem to agree that the issue is on paypal's end so I'm just going to go ahead and submit a support ticket. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: SOLVED-ish. The problem isn't fixed but the mystery of why it's happening has been solved. There's a paypal bug when the cmd parameter is set to "_donations" that it isn't carrying the option variables over to mobile. Changed it to "_xclick" as a work-around.

Comment: They would probably say that's the expected behavior as donations wouldn't typically have options like that.  I don't think donation buttons support all of those features like regular buttons do.